# I am writing a mysql query for selecting the rows from multiple tables . I am using mysql IN operator so that I can select from the given set of IDS

Tags: php

I also want to use NOT IN operator for a particular conditions .
I need to write 2 different queries inside the if statement for IN and NOT IN. Is there a way where I can combine these 2 queries into a single query . Variable $setofid will contain comma separated ID or it can be empty .

```
  if($setofid!='')
      {
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM cust_base LEFT JOIN cust_tel ON cust_base.cust_base_id=cust_tel.cust_tel_cust_id
            LEFT JOIN call_log on cust_base.cust_base_id =call_log.cust_id
             where call_log.call_log_flag1  in ($setofid)")
               }

  if($setofid=='')
      {
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM cust_base LEFT JOIN cust_tel ON cust_base.cust_base_id=cust_tel.cust_tel_cust_id
            LEFT JOIN call_log on cust_base.cust_base_id =call_log.cust_id
             where call_log.call_log_flag1   NOT in (0) ")
               }
```

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * 
FROM cust_base 
LEFT JOIN cust_tel ON cust_base.cust_base_id=cust_tel.cust_tel_cust_id
LEFT JOIN call_log on cust_base.cust_base_id =call_log.cust_id
WHERE call_log.call_log_flag1 " . ($setofid='') ? "NOT in (0)" : "in ($setofid)"` ?

Comment: These are two different queries, you execute either on or the other, so from a mysql point of view, there is no point in combining them. The php code can be shortened as Akina has demonstrated it.